# JSP How to view all session on server

Tags: jsp, http, session

I am a very newbie in JSP Dynamic Web, I have a small project that request input username for user and use HTTP session to store temporary. After user register, user will come to guest page which show the guests who are accessed the application. I must use only jsp

Please help what should I do? Anybody can give something idea to to to study?
Thank you and sorry about my bad English!

Comment: Implement a `SessionContextListener`, perhaps, or just use the login/logout handlers to add the users to an application context-scoped set (or map, etc)?

Comment: how I can handle when anyuser closes their brower?

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumeration names = session.getAttributeNames();
while (names.hasMoreElements())
{
    String val = (String)names.nextElement();
    System.out.println(val + " : " + session.getValue(val));
}
```

You can print all session names and values like this

[this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/) tutorial is quite useful

Comment: This is different, this shows attributes of a single session, not ask the users that are logged in.